# How to create array of id fields with result of checkbox value

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter

I'm iteratively building a table that includes user information for a number of users, and a checkbox to update a status field for each user. Psuedo-code from my controller:

```
foreach ($vols as $vol)
{
    $data['user_name'][] = $vol->username;
    $data['status'][] = '<input type="checkbox" name="signupStatus" /> confirm ';
}
```

The $data array is passed to a view where a table is built showing a list of users with a checkbox next to each. An admin can check the box by a user name in order to update their status in the database.

In my submit function how can I build an array that contains the username and the associated status (checkbox value).

FYI: I'm using Codeigniter, PHP5.2, MAMP

Comment: In your example code, there are no userids shown. How does a user-id is related to a checkbox?

Comment: Maybe if you explain what you're trying to do. Why would the value of your checkbox be 0? Why is the HTML for the checkbox part of the array at all?

Comment: @hakre @Cfreak - The actual use case is much more convoluted than is probably helpful - perhaps this clarifies what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($vols as $vol)
{
    $rows[$i][] = //account info here
    $rows[$i][] .= '<input type="checkbox" name="signupStatus['.$vol['id'].']" value = "0"  /> confirm ';
    // not sure where your user ID is, but I tried to guess :-)
}


// in receiving script:
// you will receive array of only those ids that were checked, so
$update_users = array_keys($_POST['signupStatus']);
// will give you an array of userids that were checked
```

Of course you should not forget to filter them so that they contained only digits. Like

```
foreach ($update_users as $key => &$userid) {
    if ( ($userid = intval($userid)) <= 0 ) {
        unset($update_users[$key]);    // silently do nothing with anything we didn't expect
    }
}
```